# Creating multiple Custom Views from XIB and adding them programmatically into ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I will start off by describing what I'm trying to accomplish and then follow by describing what I've tried already. I am pretty sure what I've tried is NOT the best approach so please correct my approach as needed!

I have a `ViewController.m` and a Custom View which is laid out in `CustomView.xib`. The custom view has `UIButtons` and `UILabels` which are populated from an Array of **Custom Objects**.

The user flow should go as such: `ViewController` starts off showing `CustomView` with its labels populated by

`CustomObjectArray[0]` -> User presses button -> Another "copy" of `CustomView` slides into the view, over the previous version.

It's labels and buttons are populated by `CustomObjectArray[1]` -> User presses button -> repeat until end of Array.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So far I made a `ViewController.m/h`, a `CustomView.m/h` AND a `CustomView.xib` file. I used interface builder to do the layout.

On the "Custom Class" tab for the top-level View in XIB file, I type in "CustomView". I also drag IBOutlets from the XIB file to the `CustomView HEADER (.h)` file.

In the `ViewController`, under -(`instancetype`) `init` method, I create a custom view using the normal `initWithNib` method. And then I do:

```
self.view = CustomViewVariableName;
```

When I run the program, the view show's up fine. However, when I try to selector's, nothing's getting recognized by the buttons:

```
[currentCustomView.continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(continueButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What did I do wrong here?

More importantly, given my described goals up top, am I even doing this right? Do I need to have `CustomView.m/h` files? Or can I do the same thing with ONLY the XIB and the `ViewController` file. Remember that I need to have "multiple copies" and slide them on top of each other until the end of my custom objects array.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Some more code as requested.

In `ViewController`:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    currentCustomView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = currentQuizQuestionView;

    .......

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [currentCustomView.continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(continuePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)continuePressed:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Current position");
    //[self moveInQuestion];
}
```

In `CustomView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *continueButton;
@end
```

In `CustomView.m`:

this is just the default page, I added nothing in this file.

`CustomView.xib`:

[image: XIB first view]

[image: XIB second view]

Comment: @sellarow12 There are so many combinations and possibilities to add or set views correctly via init() or .xib. Probably consider to simplifying your codes and sharing others for help. I think it would be easier to find a solution and answer your question :)

Comment: Is `currentCustomView.continueButton` actually set to anything? Are you passing a view controller object when loading from the NIB, as in `loadNibNamed:@"someView" owner:viewController` ?

Comment: Ok I'll add some more code of what I have done currently

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I added my code and XIB above. I **really** don't think my approach is right to begin with so please advise... Though I am able to see my xib view loaded programmatically. But clicking the button doesn't register anything.

Comment: @Allen if you get a chance can you take a look at my additions and lemme know what I'm doing wrong/if I'm even approaching it the right way to begin with?

Comment: You shouldn't do `self.view` is you can help it. You can either add subview or do the setting in **XIB**.

Comment: How do I access the buttons and labels of the view then?

Comment: Should I be using iboutlets GIVEN that I need to make multiple copies of this view and slide them over one another? As I stated in my post

Comment: @stellarowl12 I just took a look of your additions. Please take the answer I just created for a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements. Let's assume you would like to have several CustomViews as subviews of your ViewController and those subviews can be display each by each after pressing its own button.

First thing about adding subview:

```
self.view = CustomViewVariableName;
```

Since CustomsViews will be subviews according to my assumption, above line is an error. You probably would like to have something like this.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    CustomView *v = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNib];
    [v.button addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(continuePressed:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```

Second, I noticed you would like to have an array as a handler to refer all the subviews. We can add above CustomView into a mutable array by insert one more line into above for-loop.

```
[_customObjectArray addObject:v.button];
```

Finally, I created a simple project and tried to implement things you mentioned. Maybe you can take it for a reference. https://db.tt/Och2tzyG

Comment: Hey @Allen I am going to take a look at your project but I just wanted to clarify. I am trying to make it kinda like Tinder (the dating app where you swipe onto the next person). So it's all based on one "Custom View" and when you press a button on the screen then next one slides into the screen over the previous view. And it repeats until you're done. Will that work with what you wrote up there?

Comment: And the custom objects array would contain "People objects" from which each Custom view would be populated. So first one showing up would be (Sally, 26, SF), second one would be (Rachel, 28, LA), etc.

Comment: Also should I even have the CustomView.m/.h file? Or is that wholly unnecessary and I can just stick with the XIB and the ViewController

Comment: @stellarowl12 I didn't implement swipe animation in the project; however, you will see the subview display will be changed once you press the button in a subview.

Comment: @stellarowl12 In this case, I prefer to having CustomView.m/.h in my opinion. I have them in the project too.

Comment: @stellarowl12 The project I created just gave you a rough idea. You still can design your own custom objects as your wish.

Comment: Awesome, I took a look I think it will help me big time. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102852/discussion-between-stellarowl12-and-allen).